# Email Authentication with Mailchimp and Bluehost

Tags: authentication, mailchimp, bluehost, spf, dkim

Can someone please help me get this right. I've been trying for days and just can't do it.

This is what mail chimp is asking me to do.

```
Set a TXT (SPF) record for averyburch.com to:
v=spf1 include:servers.mcsv.net ?all

Set the CNAME record for k1._domainkey.averyburch.com to:
dkim.mcsv.net
```

So I have entered the following in my bluehost DNS zone editor. But it's not authenticating. I've waited 48 hours.

CNAME
`k1._domainkey`  points to  `dkim.mcsv.net`

TXT
@ txt value is: `v=spf1 a mx ptr include:bluehost.com include:servers.mcsv.net ?all`

I did enter exactly k1._domainkey.averyburch.com but the control panel seems to change it to k1._domainkey. Everything in the spf record is the bluehost default setting apart from include:servers.mcsv.net which i added.
Can someone please tell me what I'm messing up. I'm not experienced with this. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 2):

This is instructions I followed from [someone else on another forum](http://www.bluehostforum.com/showthread.php?143861-Bluehost-say-they-no-longer-support-DKIM) that worked perfectly the first time:

> Hey all,
>
> I have been looking into this because of wanting to use DKIM support
>   for MailChimp emails. Most of this stuff is above my pay grade, but I
>   was able to successfully set up DKIM. Here's how it went:
>
> Here are the instructions from MailChimp:
>
> DKIM: Create a CNAME record for k1._domainkey.[example.com] with this
>   value: dkim.mcsv.net
>
> SPF: Create a TXT record for [example.com] with: v=spf1
>   include:servers.mcsv.net ?all
>
> I then logged into my Bluehost account: cPanel -> DNS Zone Editor
>
> I chose the domain I wanted in the dropdown menu and filled out the
>   following:
>
> Host Record: k1._domainkey.[example.com]  TTL: 14400 (the default)
>   Type: CNAME  Points To: dkim.mcsv.net
>
> Then I clicked "Add Record," and it added successfully.
>
> Then I filled out another entry:
>
> Host Record: [example.com]  TTL: 14400 (the default) Type: TXT  Points
>   To: v=spf1 include:servers.mcsv.net ?all**
>
> "Add Record," and it was all set. Both entries showed up in the list
>   below.
>
> I was able to use this methods for two domains, and MailChimp verified
>   that it went through, and they have authenticated DKIM and SPF
>   records.
>
> Hope that helps. Thanks for the thread.

Comment: I too am trying to add this dkim came record but it wont let me ? It just says 'Could not add zone record'. Trying to add -  k1._domainkey.wonkhe.com with this value: dkim.mcsv.net    this looks like it should work to me?

Answer (score 0):

So there are a couple of issues that are immediately apparent:

1. The DKIM key is malformed.  Looking at the DNS the key record is "k=rsa; p=MIGfMA0GCSqG...".  That's missing the initial prefix.  It should be "v=DKIM1;k=rsa;p=MIGfMA0GCSqG...".  Ideally if you fix that, DKIM signatures will start working
2. The SPF record you've got in place exceeds the allowed domain lookup limit of 10.  You can see some info here - https://dmarcian.com/spf-survey/averyburch.com .  Solving this for situations like yours is non-trivial.  (Full disclosure, my company ValiMail is about to roll out tech to address a number of common email authentication issues, including this one).

For the moment, assuming DKIM starts working, I wouldn't worry too much about the SPF issue.

Make the DKIM change noted above, and see if that at least gets DKIM authentication working.  If you want some visibility, you may also want to add a DMARC record so you can see whether email is authenticating or failing.